# render called before SetState is complete - how do I manage this?

Tags: reactjs

**edit: I completely rewrote the body of this question to better reflect what I asking**

I'm trying to figure out how to ensure that my component state has changed its value before render() is called.

**The workflow:**

I have a component that's a simple item with a icon to be clicked. When the item is clicked, I change state, and want to reflect that change in the UI by changing the background color.

The problem is that when the icon is clicked, my handleClick fires fine, I do SetState, which in turn calls render() - but inside render when I check the state value, it still has the old value. I'm aware SetState is an Async operation - so how do we solve for this simple situation of changing the display of a component on an event triggered on it?

**Code:**

```
class Item extends React.Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    this.state = {
      complete: this.props.complete,
    };
  }

  handleClick(e) {
    if (e === "completed") {
      this.setState({ complete: !this.state.complete });
    }
  }

 render() {
    var divId = "d_" + this.props.s;
    var boxClass = CssMap.forComplete(this.state.complete); //still shows old value!
    return (
      <div className={boxClass}>
        <div id={divId}>this.props.s</div>
        <span>
          <i className="icon ion-ios-checkmark-outline size-16" onClick={() => this.handleClick('completed') } />
        </span>
      </div>
 );
}};
```

Here's a console.log sample

```
componentWillUpdate: complete
app.min.js:428 calling render
app.min.js:399 handleClick alert alert-danger | icon ion-ios-star-outline size-16
```

As you can see, the handleClick complete async event (which I added recently) is getting called after render()!

Comment: That's not valid javascript. Your might want `var someClass = this.state.somevar ? "xxx" : "yyy";`

Comment: There is also no "async" code in your `handleClick` function. Please show us your actual code.

Comment: I typed that code only to show the flow. My internal code is fine. I want to understand how to manage render getting called before setState takes effect. There is no async portion for my code but there's nothing I need to do there.

Comment: If you're showing example code that doesn't exhibit the problem your real code is having, it becomes quite difficult for people to help you.

Comment: I've rewritten the question entirely, hopefully much clearer this time. Thank you.

Comment: Seems to be working as expected: https://jsbin.com/duganimupe/1/edit?js,console,output

Comment: @robertklep I don't get it. When iI run it, it's very clear that the render() is getting called before the state values take effect. So the visual state is always one step behind the state I set! Even the console.log sequence shows render() getting called before the SetState completion callback is called.

Comment: @Gerry I'm seeing _"rendering, class = uncompleted"_, _"clicked"_, _"rendering, class = completed"_. You're seeing something else?

Comment: @robertklep not on your jsbin, but on my code running locally. I solved it for now, using props settings instead of state. A battle for another day.

Comment: @Gerry if you ever want people to help you out better, please be more complete. The code you're posting here is obviously not the code that's causing the problems (nor can the problems be reproduced by it). One thing: it's not related to `setState` being async, as React will only call `render` after it has actually changed the state.

Answer (score 1):

your problem is with if statement.not bad if you see [this link](http://javascript.about.com/od/decisionmaking/a/des10.htm).

```
  render() {
      ...
      var someClass = this.state.somevar? "xxx" : "yyy";
      return (<div className={someClass} onClick={() =>this.handleClick()}>....</div>);
    }

    handleClick(e) {
      this.setState({somevar: !this.state.somevar});
    }
```

Comment: Please see my comment above. My internal code is fine. I'm trying to figure out how to get render to execute after my setState.

Comment: your problem is render not execute after setState?

Comment: no, my problem is the state not having changed. I've rewritten the question completely, please take a look. Thanks!